# Split DateTimeIndex data based on hour/minute/second

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

I have time-series data that I would like to split based on hour, or minute, or second. This is generally user-defined. I would like to know how it can be done.

For example, consider the following:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': pd.date_range(start='2016-09-30',
                                           freq='600s', periods=20)})
test['X'] = np.arange(20)
```

The output is:

```
    TIME                X
0   2016-09-30 00:00:00 0
1   2016-09-30 00:10:00 1
2   2016-09-30 00:20:00 2
3   2016-09-30 00:30:00 3
4   2016-09-30 00:40:00 4
5   2016-09-30 00:50:00 5
6   2016-09-30 01:00:00 6
7   2016-09-30 01:10:00 7
8   2016-09-30 01:20:00 8
9   2016-09-30 01:30:00 9
10  2016-09-30 01:40:00 10
11  2016-09-30 01:50:00 11
12  2016-09-30 02:00:00 12
13  2016-09-30 02:10:00 13
14  2016-09-30 02:20:00 14
15  2016-09-30 02:30:00 15
16  2016-09-30 02:40:00 16
17  2016-09-30 02:50:00 17
18  2016-09-30 03:00:00 18
19  2016-09-30 03:10:00 19
```

Suppose I want to split it by hour. I would like the following as one chunk which I can then save to a file.

```
    TIME                X
0   2016-09-30 00:00:00 0
1   2016-09-30 00:10:00 1
2   2016-09-30 00:20:00 2
3   2016-09-30 00:30:00 3
4   2016-09-30 00:40:00 4
5   2016-09-30 00:50:00 5
```

The second chunk would be:

```
    TIME                X
0   2016-09-30 01:00:00 6
1   2016-09-30 01:10:00 7
2   2016-09-30 01:20:00 8
3   2016-09-30 01:30:00 9
4   2016-09-30 01:40:00 10
5   2016-09-30 01:50:00 11
```

and so on...

Note I can do it purely based on logical conditions such as,

```
 df[(df['TIME'] >= '2016-09-30 00:00:00') &
    (df['TIME'] <= '2016-09-30 00:50:00')]
```

and repeat....

but what if my sampling changes? Is there a way to create a mask or something that takes less amount of code and is efficient? I have 10 GB of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `groupby` for this, and the grouping should be based on date and hour:

```
test['DATE'] = test['TIME'].dt.date
test['HOUR'] = test['TIME'].dt.hour
grp = test.groupby(['DATE', 'HOUR'])
```

You can then loop over the groups and do the operation you want.

Example:

```
for key, df in grp:
    print(key, df)
```

> ```
> ((datetime.date(2016, 9, 30), 0),                  TIME  X        DATE  HOUR
> 0 2016-09-30 00:00:00  0  2016-09-30     0
> 1 2016-09-30 00:10:00  1  2016-09-30     0
> 2 2016-09-30 00:20:00  2  2016-09-30     0
> 3 2016-09-30 00:30:00  3  2016-09-30     0
> 4 2016-09-30 00:40:00  4  2016-09-30     0
> 5 2016-09-30 00:50:00  5  2016-09-30     0)
>
>
> ((datetime.date(2016, 9, 30), 1),                   TIME   X        DATE  HOUR
> 6  2016-09-30 01:00:00   6  2016-09-30     1
> 7  2016-09-30 01:10:00   7  2016-09-30     1
> 8  2016-09-30 01:20:00   8  2016-09-30     1
> 9  2016-09-30 01:30:00   9  2016-09-30     1
> 10 2016-09-30 01:40:00  10  2016-09-30     1
> 11 2016-09-30 01:50:00  11  2016-09-30     1)
>
>
> ((datetime.date(2016, 9, 30), 2),                   TIME   X        DATE  HOUR
> 12 2016-09-30 02:00:00  12  2016-09-30     2
> 13 2016-09-30 02:10:00  13  2016-09-30     2
> 14 2016-09-30 02:20:00  14  2016-09-30     2
> 15 2016-09-30 02:30:00  15  2016-09-30     2
> 16 2016-09-30 02:40:00  16  2016-09-30     2
> 17 2016-09-30 02:50:00  17  2016-09-30     2)
>
>
> ((datetime.date(2016, 9, 30), 3),                   TIME   X        DATE  HOUR
> 18 2016-09-30 03:00:00  18  2016-09-30     3
> 19 2016-09-30 03:10:00  19  2016-09-30     3)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

***Option 1***
you can groupby series without having them in the object you're grouping.

```
test.groupby([test.TIME.dt.date,
              test.TIME.dt.hour,
              test.TIME.dt.minute,
              test.TIME.dt.second]):
```

***Option 2***
use `pd.TimeGrouper`

```
test.set_index('TIME').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('S'))  # Group by seconds
test.set_index('TIME').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('T'))  # Group by minutes
test.set_index('TIME').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H'))  # Group by hours
```